# How to select several specific elements in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of integers as mentioned below.

`List<int> numbers=new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6};`

and I would like to select numbers, that are in an array of integers:

`int[] somenumbers=new int[]{1,3,5};`

how can I do this with LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int[] somenumbers = new int[] { 1, 3, 5 };
var result = numbers.Where(x => somenumbers.Contains(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Intersect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-5.0) to get the common elements between 2 `IEnumerable<T>`s :

```
List<int> numbers=new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6};
int[] somenumbers=new int[]{1,3,5, 42};
    
var commonNumbers = numbers.Intersect(somenumbers);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", commonNumbers)); // 1, 3, 5
```

Note that the order of the collections to compare doesn't matter :

```
commonNumbers = somenumbers.Intersect(numbers);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", commonNumbers)); // 1, 3, 5
```

[Try it yourself](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fr3COr)